# Templates, variables processing with regexp in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have multi-line string with some variables like `$Item_#1_Value$`, `$Item_#2_Value$`, and so on. I would like to replace (case in-sensitive) all these instances with real values, which is not a problem with `str_ireplace()`.

The problem is I need to remove also all spaces which may (or may not) be adjacent to these variables. The other spaces, not adjacent to variables, I need to not touch.

For example:
If `$item_#1_Value$` is `1234`, so strings: 
`ABC$item_#1_Value$QWERT`, `ABC $ITEM_#1_VALUE$    QWERT`, `ABC $item_#1_Value$ QWERT` all needs to be replaced to `ABC1234QWERT`.

I have understood it should be `preg_replace(...)` used instead of `str_ireplace(...)`, but I cannot realize what regexp pattern should I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it with regular expressions would be to match your tag with optional surrounding multiple whitespace:

```
\s*\$item_#1_Value\$\s*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nrsvk3/2)

*PHP Code*

```
<?php
$strings[] = 'ABC$item_#1_Value$QWERT';
$strings[] = 'ABC $ITEM_#1_VALUE$ QWERT';
$strings[] = 'ABC $item_#1_Value$ QWERT';
foreach ($strings as $string) {
    $string = preg_replace('/\s*\$item_#1_Value\$\s*/i', "1234", $string);
    echo $string.PHP_EOL;
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/XW1AP)

*Result*

> ABC1234QWERT
>
> ABC1234QWERT
>
> ABC1234QWERT

Comment: Your first answer is not suitable, it will remove ALL spaces, not only adjacent. I did not provide samples with those spaces, but I have mentioned it in my explanation. 
Second suggestion seems like exactly what I need, thank you, will go to test.

Comment: @SergeS I seem to have missed that part, sorry. I've updated the answer. Notice the second answer is edited too to meet your needs.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you again.

Comment: Happy to help my friend.